# Ambiguity in innerHTML property

Tags: javascript, document, innerhtml

```
<div><p><p></p></p></div>
<script>
alert(document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML);
</script>
```

Execute the code

I found something unusual the alert shows me `3<p>` elements. Well I have declared only two.
its actually showing one more than declared. Someone explain this.

Answer (score 2):

you can't have paragraphs inside paragraphs.
try this:

```
<div><p></p><p></p></div>
<script>
alert(document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML);
</script>
```